# Auto-complete and searching across different indexes in elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, search, elastic-stack, autosuggest

I'm trying to implement auto-completion and search across all the indexes using elastic search in NodeJS. I am using [@elastic/elastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/elasticsearch).

When I started researching how searching can be done across different indexes, I stumbled upon a few methods that were helpful. But [multi_match_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) seems like it'll do the job. So i implemented like below:

```js
const { body: { hits } } = await client.search({
            // skipped mentioning index to search across all indexes
            body: { query: {
                multi_match: {
                    query: req.query.q,
                    fuzziness: 1
                }
            }
        }});
```

Any pointers, if there is any better way to implement the above scenario would be great.

But the main question is, I couldn't find a way to implement auto-completion across different indexes. tried using [suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html) but this doesn't seem to work well across different indexes and works great only with a single index.

Could anyone help me with auto-suggestions across different indexes?